# How to access UI elements in a canvas in UnityUI

Tags: unity, c#

I am looking for elements on a canvas (a textfield and a slider); so I can retrieve values and pass them to a function.

But so far I can't figure out how to access them; I can see the methods of the canvas itself, but I can't see the name of the elements that I did add on the canvas.

I have the canvas saved in a variable which is public; then I did place a slider and textfield, connected to text labels; but I can't seem to access neither the label nor the slider or textfield.

```
Canvas --
        |___ Text
        |        |_____ InputField
        |
        |___ Text
                 |_____ Slider
```

I did plan to access to the text value in the input field doing something like canvas.text.inputfield.text, but this does not work, since I can't see the name of the text field when using dot notation. Same goes for the slider.

```
public Canvas mainmenu;

void Start() {
    mainmenu = mainmenu.Getomponent<Canvas>();
}

public RetrieveData(){
    // dot notation does not find sub elements of mainmenu canvas
    // only the properties and methods of the canvas itself.
}
```

How do you actually access elements on a UI canvas, if you can't see them directly, even if they are parented to other elements?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend against finding GameObjects by name (using `GameObject.Find` or `transform.Find` as suggested in the existing answers) whenever you can avoid it.

In my experience this tends to lead to brittle relationships between scripts that are easy to break accidentally, and [other more exotic bugs](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/672973048899702784).

The most reliable method, if you have a script that needs to use a particular `InputField` and `Slider`, is to **give it public/serialized fields of these types**:

```
public class MyUIForm : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField inputField;
    public Slider slider;
    ...
```

**...and wire them up in the Inspector.**

This makes the dependency between these objects *explicit* to anyone using the editor - as soon as you attach this script, the Inspector tells you what it needs.

This dependency is also visible to Unity so it knows which assets need to be included together in a build, if they're not all scene objects. And these references are populated immediately when the object is loaded, which avoids common order-of-execution problems when one script tries to access fields of another one that hasn't had time to `Start()` yet.

Adding another object of the same type or the same name or changing the parenting hierarchy won't accidentally break this, because the object has a direct reference. Even in a scene with 100 similarly-named/functioning objects, you have the ability to specify the exact one you want.

If these objects don't exist in the same scene, you can also create intermediate scripts that hold these references. eg. a `MainMenu` script that knows about each of its child pages like `HighScoresMenu` and `SettingsMenu`, and `SettingsMenu` holding references to its inputs `PlayerNameField` and `GammaSlider`. Then if another script needs access to these fields (not sure why - any script using them should probably live in `SettingsMenu`, but let's assume there's a good reason) - it can get a reference to the `MainMenu` instance and use `mainMenu.settingsMenu.gammaSlider`. These intermediate scripts are cheap, and save the rest of your code from needing to know the guts of how your menu is organized in the hierarchy, as well as centralizing the work of wiring up scripts in the inspector.

---

If you want to wire it up more automatically, you can also use [GetComponentInChildren](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html):

```
public Canvas mainMenu;
private InputField _inputField;

void Start()
{
    _inputField = mainMenu.GetComponentInChildren<InputField>();
}
```

This will search the child hierarchy of `mainMenu`, including grandchildren and so on, until it finds something with an `InputField` component and return that. (You can also use GetComponent**s**InChildren to get an array of all matches)

This has some of the same problems as finding an object by name (moving the `InputField` to a new parent could cause us to miss it; adding another unrelated `InputField` could cause us to grab the wrong one), but we do know we're getting the right type back. It also won't be broken by someone trying to improve readability by changing the object named "InputField" to be named "PlayerNameInput" or just fixing a typo/capitalization.

When used with your own types that are explicit about their use, like the `SettingsMenu` example above, these risks largely disappear. You might create a form with two `InputField`s, but you're unlikely to ever use two copies of the `SettingsMenu`, so if the `MainMenu` script used `GetComponentInChildren` to find it instead of a direct reference, it's unlikely to ever be broken accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you brought Canvas itself and you are trying to access gameObject's properties. So for that try,

```
mainmenu.transform.Find.......
```

Comment: You can access `mainmenu.transform` directly - no need to go via `.gameObject`. That said, I have some reservations about code wiring itself up by names. In any project I've worked on for more than a week or two, this has started to lead to bugs, from people changing names they didn't know were important, or duplicating objects, or trying to use prefabs, or fixing typos, or... ;)

Comment: As far as your this "You can access mainmenu.transform directly" is concerned, you are right. rest is just exact about the solution what he asked.

Comment: OP asked how to access UI components. The only way they could think to do this is by name (likely since this is how it's done in ActionScript and similar environments) but that does *not* mean this is the only kind of solution we should offer.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possibilities here.

- You can use the static function **GameObject.Find()** to find a gameobject by
  name in the entire scene. However, this function is a bit slow so try
  to call it only once.
- You can also use the non-static function **Transform.Find()** that will only search
  in the childrens of the transform. Transform.FindChild is deprecated
  and is the same as Transform.Find().

Comment: `GameObject.Find()` will give you the first gameObject in hierarchy. It cannot be use to find same named objects as OP did show in question, as far as your point of FindChild is concern, you could edit the answer or leave comment if there is no big change or mistake