# Referencing multiple canvas images through script in C#

Tags: unity, c#

What is the best way to reference multiple Canvas Images within C# script attached to my player in Unity?

Currently I have something similar too:

```
public Image image;

//Finds the Image Object being referenced.
image = GameObject.Find ("Canvas/Image").GetComponent<Image> ();
```

Comment: [You may find this answer useful](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/115996/how-to-access-ui-elements-in-a-canvas-in-unityui/116011#116011). It recommends wiring up this kind of relationship in the Inspector, so that changes to your scene/prefab hierarchy don't accidentally cause "Find"-based methods to find the wrong object, or none at all.

Comment: Personally when referencing large numbers of objects I like to create a separate class e.g. `ExampleClassReferences` for my script `ExampleClass` which contains all the references as public objects and mark it as `[System.Serializable]`. I then have a public  instance of `ExampleClassReferences` in `ExampleClass` so I can then assign them all in the inspector and minimize the class to stop it taking up loads of space. (Ofc if you are instantiating the object with `ExampleClass` some of the references may not carry over, this also may not be the best practice not sure)

Answer (score 1):

Well, as far as I understand your question, you can assign whole array on `Image` type.

```
public Image[] images;

//Finds the Image Object being referenced.
images = FindObjectOfType<Canvas> ().transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Image> ();
```